# Cannot read property 'header' of underdefined when creating jwt verify module

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I followed this video to create jwt authenticaion. https://youtu.be/2jqok-WgelI?t=4284

It occured the error when I try to use verifyToken module like the video at 1:11:00

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined

Here is my code

verifyToken.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(req,res,next) {
    const token=req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send('Access denied');
    try{
        const verified = jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    }catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send('Wrong token');
    }
};
```

index.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const info = require('../public/info');
const verify = require('./verifyToken');

//render main page
router.get("/",function (req,res) {
    res.render('index',{
        title:info.title[0],
        content:info.news
    });
});
//try to use verifyToken module here
router.get("/create",verify(),function (req,res,next) {
    res.render('index',{
        title:info.title[1],
        content:info.create
    });
});
//render about page
router.get("/about",function (req,res) {
    res.render('index',{
        title:info.title[2],
        content:info.info
    });
});
//render sign up page
router.get("/signup",function (req,res) {
    res.render('register');
});
//render login page
router.get("/login",function (req,res) {
    res.render('login');
});


module.exports=router;
```

Comment: what is the error and and what have you tried so far?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try to add a function callback pointer of verify i.e. Without () to the router get method parameters as in the video:

```
   router.get("/create", verify ,function (req,res,next) {
       res.render('index',{
          title:info.title[1],
          content:info.create
       });
   });
```